# How do i ground a new overhead light fixture? I'm replacing a 2 wire fixture with a new 3 wire fixture wich includes a ground wire

Tags: electrical, grounding, light

How do I ground a new overhead light fixture?  I'm replacing a 2 wire fixture with no grounding wire with a new 3 wire fixture which includes a ground wire.[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the light fixture box please?

Comment: I have a photo as requested but I don't know how to post it.  If you give me your e-mail ThreePhaseEel, I can send it to you

Comment: You should be able hit the "edit" link in "share edit..." in your post and then use the button that looks like a mountain-and-sun painting to add the picture to your post.  If that doesn't work, post a comment and we can help you from there

Comment: Ah, I meant the box in the wall, not the actual fixture itself, my apologies!  So, could you post another photo please?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the box in the wall.  Can you explain further?

Comment: @MichaelO'Haver: In the usual circumstances a light _fixture_ is mounted over a _box_ that is permanently installed in a wall or ceiling. The box is not meant to be visible; the fixture should completely cover it. Furthermore, the box is usually fully enclosed except on its side facing the room. All of the wires that are needed to connect the fixture _must_ be in the box. In this case that means that there must be three wires in the box. If you just connect two wires the fixture may work but there is a danger of electrical shock.

Comment: OK.  What do I do when there are only 2 wires from the old fixture?  The new fixture seems to be grounded to the fixture frame.  Is that sufficient?